# Sentry 2 + Laravel 4 filter redirect not working

Tags: php, rest, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I'm using Laravel 4 with Sentry 2 and everything seems to be working fine, except for this:

When the user is not logged in, instead of redirecting him to the login page with a flash message, it always 404. I've tried many things, got different filters from different projects, tried different redirects, but nothing seems to be working. here is my filter right now

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application & Route Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Below you will find the "before" and "after" events for the application
| which may be used to do any work before or after a request into your
| application. Here you may also register your custom route filters.
|
*/

/*App::before(function ($request) {
    //
});

App::after(function ($request, $response) {
    //
});*/


App::before(function ($request) {
    //
});


App::after(function ($request, $response) {
    //
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following filters are used to verify that the user of the current
| session is logged into this application. The "basic" filter easily
| integrates HTTP Basic authentication for quick, simple checking.
|
*/

/*Route::filter('auth', function () {
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});

Route::filter('auth.basic', function () {
    return Auth::basic();
});
*/

Route::filter('auth', function () {
    if (!Sentry::check()) return Redirect::route('login');
});

Route::filter('inGroup', function ($route, $request, $value) {
    if (!Sentry::check()) return Redirect::route('login');

    // we need to determine if a non admin user
    // is trying to access their own account.
    $userId = Route::input('users');

    try {
        $user = Sentry::getUser();

        $group = Sentry::findGroupByName($value);

        if ($userId != Session::get('userId') && (!$user->inGroup($group))) {
            Session::flash('error', trans('users.noaccess'));

            return Redirect::route('home');
        }
    } catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e) {
        Session::flash('error', trans('users.notfound'));

        return Redirect::route('login');
    } catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\GroupNotFoundException $e) {
        Session::flash('error', trans('groups.notfound'));

        return Redirect::route('login');
    }
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Guest Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The "guest" filter is the counterpart of the authentication filters as
| it simply checks that the current user is not logged in. A redirect
| response will be issued if they are, which you may freely change.
|
*/

/*Route::filter('guest', function () {
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});*/

Route::filter('guest', function () {
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CSRF Protection Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The CSRF filter is responsible for protecting your application against
| cross-site request forgery attacks. If this special token in a user
| session does not match the one given in this request, we'll bail.
|
*/

/*Route::filter('csrf', function () {
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token')) {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});*/

Route::filter('csrf', function () {
    // var_dump($_SESSION);
    //            var_dump($_POST);
    //            die();

    // TODO: Rewrite this tree of conditionals
    if (Session::token() !== Input::get('_token') || Session::token() === NULL || Input::get('_token') === NULL) {
        // Session token and form tokens do not match or one is empty
        if (App::environment() === 'testing') {
            // We only want to allow CSRF override if we're running tests
            if (Input::get('IgnoreCSRFTokenError') === TRUE) {
                // Allow CSRF override in testing environment
                return;
            } else {
                // Handle CSRF normally
                throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
            }
        } else {
            // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart

            // Handle CSRF normally
            throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;

            // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
        }
    }
});

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// ############# Sentry group permissions #############

Route::filter('sentryAuth', function () {
    if (!Sentry::check()) {
        return Redirect::guest('login')->with('flashMessage', Lang::get('flashMessages.login_required'));
    }
});
```

**ROUTE :**

```
<?php


Route::group(array('before' => "sentryAuth"), function () {

    Route::controller('products', 'ProductsController');
});
```

Sorry if I was not clear enough. Let me know and I'll clarify. I really appreciate any help that will lead me to solve this problem. Again, the filter does prevent the user from accessing the page, but it 404 instead of redirecting to the login page.

Thank you.